# Angularjs tab button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi! I was wondering how to **use the tab button on the keyboard to call a function**?  Something like this:

```
<button 
    class="btn btn-primary order-input-add" 
    ui-keypress="{13:'add_plu(order.orderwindow.add_field)'}" 
    ng-click="add_plu(order.orderwindow.add_field)">Add
</button>
```

This code segment allows me to press "enter" to call function `"add_plu()"`.  This uses angular ui utility library.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried it.

Comment: What about if you use ui-keydown instead of ui-keypress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `keypress` event is fired when a key is pressed down and that key normally produces a character value.

You can use the `keydown` event instead:

```
ui-keydown="{ 'tab':'add_plu(order.orderwindow.add_field)'}"
```

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/XMRlVLnw2BEyoVgvQyW9?p=preview

Note that you need to click the button first to give it focus, which is another issue.